# Special non-utf-8 characters appearing in feed imported from a windows based system?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I have a custom feed importer that import content from an external feed. The import happens on cron and everything is working fine except that the content comes with special non-utf-8 characters. I looked on stackoverflow and there are a few suggestions about how to do this in code, I tried couple and it has not worked for me yet. I am hoping to see if there is a drupal way of handling it.
The character that I am having problem with is `Â`. It represent a space I believe and it only appear at end/and beginning of sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Feeds Tamper](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module to do this with a [custom plugin](https://drupal.org/node/1246602).

In your module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_directory().
 */
function MYMODULE_ctools_plugin_directory($owner, $plugin_type){
  if ($owner == 'feeds_tamper' && $plugin_type == 'plugins') {
    return 'plugins';
  }
}
```

and in your module/plugins/utf8_encode.inc

```
$plugin = array(
  'form' => 'MYMODULE_utf8_encode_form',
  'callback' => 'MYMODULE_utf8_encode_callback',
  'name' => 'Convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8',
  'multi' => 'loop',
  'category' => 'Text',
);

function MYMODULE_utf8_encode_form($importer, $element_key, $settings) {
  $form = array();
  $form['html'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('This will convert all ISO-8859-1 characters to their UTF-8 equivalents.'
),
  );
  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_utf8_encode_callback($result, $item_key, $element_key, &$field, $settings, $source) {
  $field = utf8_encode($field);
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you can use one of the [strip-non-UTF8 regex functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string) to do it in the callback instead.  I use

```
$regex = '/((?:[\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}){1,100})|./x';

preg_replace($regex, '$1', $field);
```

Comment: I thought I submitted both of these plugins to the Feeds Tamper issue queue, as UTF8 issues are rather common when getting data from Windows systems.  Apparently, I forgot, but I will do so.

Comment: Thank you. It is already a custom importer using feeds hooks (Classes/mehtods) I guess I will give your solution a try in one of the hooks/methods implemented and will report back. Also, I am going to try `drupal_convert_to_utf8`

Comment: @awm You learn something new every day.  I didn't realize that function existed.

Comment: the regex (at the bottom of your answer) worked better than anything else. I had already tried utf8_encode with success to get remove other non-utf8 chars but not the `Â`. Same result with `drupal_convert_to_utf8`. I will probably use a combination to be secure.

Comment: @awm FWIW, I made this https://drupal.org/node/2263119

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the special characters with empty string in
        **hook_feeds_after_parse** like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_feeds_after_parse().
 */
function mymodule_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
  //Replace special characters with '' to prevent PDO exception
  foreach($result->items as $item_key => &$item) {
    foreach ($item as $sub_item_key => $sub_item) {
      $item[$sub_item_key] = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x10\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x19\x7F]'
      . '|[\x00-\x7F][\x80-\xBF]+'
      . '|([\xC0\xC1]|[\xF0-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF]*'
      . '|[\xC2-\xDF]((?![\x80-\xBF])|[\x80-\xBF]{2,})'
      . '|[\xE0-\xEF](([\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]))'
      . '|(?![\x80-\xBF]{2})|[\x80-\xBF]{3,})/S',
      '', $item[$sub_item_key]);
    }
  }
```